# Using ng-repeat with Json Data

Tags: json, angularjs

I could not display the json data using ng-repeat when i am attempting a simple app. On Console, the data in Json file is displayed. The error thrown is  [ngRepeat:dupes]. I am using Google Chrome and Xampp.

```
<html ng-app="myAPP">
<script>
var myapp = angular.module("myAPP", []);

myapp.controller('simplectrl', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get('countries.json').success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.countries=data;

    });
});



</script>


<body ng-controller="simplectrl">

<h3> Country Data </h3>

<table>
    <tr>
    <th> Country </th>
    <th> Population </th>
    </tr>


    <tr ng-repeat="country in countries track by country.name" >
    <td> {{country.name}}</td>
    <td>{{country.population}}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>

</body>
</hmtl>
```

**Countries.json:**

```
{ "countries" :[
               { "name": "China", "population" :"1.4billion" },
               { "name": "India", "population" :"1.2billion" },
               { "name": "USA", "population":"300million" }
]};
```

I followed some of the solutions suggested in SO with no success. Some suggested using track by $index or using track by country.name in ng-repeat. Please help me out. thanks

Comment: track by $index instead?

Comment: do u have same country name more than once ?

Comment: no error using track by $index , still names and popluation are not displayed.

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha json file does not have duplicate country names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mathieu Bertin said you should change implementation of your callback GET method.

```
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.countries=data.countries;
});
```

I've created [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJ5BR/1964/) with working example for you.

Comment: thanks for the example. JSFiddle example is Working fine. But when i tried in my file on local server, country name & population is not displayed. what could be the problem?

Comment: @kishan, If you are using my JSFiddle example on your local machine, please change request type on 'GET' and change URL. I've used JSFiddle API for emulate JSON responce.

Answer (score 0):

just change the callback for your get method

```
$http.get('countries.json').success(function (data) {
   $scope.countries = data.countries; // because actually countries is an object with a key countries containing all country 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**The other mistake I found out in my code is putting semicolon at the end in JSON file.** As pointed The statement must be `$scope.countries= data.countries` for the data written in the JSON file. To use `$scope.countries= data`, the data in JSON file should be modified. Sorry if I wasted anybody's time with my silly mistake.

To rectify the problem, I read about 20 questions on this topic, spending couple of hours. It was great learning in this process. Such silly mistakes are usually taking lot of time than the bigger issues. **Newbies must be exta careful with syntax errors while learning any programming language** *(self-note)*.